# Некорректная работа библиотеки RedBeanPHP на OpenServer

Tags: php, база-данных, openserver, redbeanphp

Раньше всё работало нормально. Но последнее время при выполнении функций:

```
$somebean = R::dispense('sometable');
...
R::store($somebean); //<-- эта строка генерирует ошибку
```

библиотеки RedBeanPHP, в том случае, когда мы добавляем запись в уже имеющуюся таблицу, возникает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught [23000] - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 **Column 'id' cannot be null** trace: #0 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(1035): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('INSERT INTO us...', Array) #1 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(1072): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll('INSERT INTO us...', Array) #2 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(4246): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetOne('INSERT INTO us...', Array) #3 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(5762): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getCell('INSERT INTO us...', Array, 0) #4 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(5889): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->insertRecord('users', Array, Array) #5 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(8651): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\AQueryWriter->updateRecord('users', Array, 0) #6 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(8222): RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->storeBean(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)) #7 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php(9371): RedBeanPHP\Repository->store(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)) #8 W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php in W:\domains\EOPMS\eopms\libs\rb.php on line 768

Ключевую фразу выделил жирным. Не понимаю, как может колонка `id` принимать значение `null`, когда я вызываю `R::dispense('sometable')` и идентификатор строки присваивается автоматически.

Также при вызове скрипта с функцией `R::store($somebean)` из консоли, происходит зависание, даже в том случае, когда добавляется запись в новую таблицу.

На арендованном сервере выполнение тех же самых скриптов абсолютно не вызывает никаких неполадок, то есть дело явно не в неправильно написанном коде.

Кто сталкивался с подобным поведением OpenServer? Может быть там просто случайно сбились какие-то настройки? Текущая версия OpenServer 5.2.2.

Comment: `auto_increment` то стоит у столбца? Если код одинаков, значит БД разная

Comment: Ну явно дело в БД, или нет автоинкрементации, или особенности конфига MySQL, можно попробовать сравнить. Например, у нас недавно сломалась БД старой CRM после переезда с 5.6 на 5.7 из-за новых ограничений

Comment: @teran, спасибо большое. Можете в ответ написать, чтобы я отметил как правильный? И странно, я экспортировал БЛ с арендованного сервера, и импортировал в OS. Я посмотрел, на арендованом все ключи стоят. Как они могли сброситься при переносе - непонятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку ошибка утверждает, что значение столбца `null`, а используемый код одинаков и работает на разных серверах, то различия следует искать в БД.
Т.к. речь идет о ключевом столбце таблицы и о запросе на вставку, то, очевидно, его значение не генерируется автоматически, то есть столбец не автоинкрементный.

Comment: Спасибо большое, всё так и есть)))